# How to inject an appengine.Context in martini

Tags: google-app-engine, go, martini

When I try to inject an appengine.Context from a middleware doing this:

```
//Share Context
m.Use(func(r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    c, err := appengine.Namespace(c, namespace)
    if err != nil {
        c.Debugf("[Namespace] %s", err)
    }
    m.Map(c)
})
```

I get this Panic saying that apparently there is no appengine.Context to be injected:

## PANIC

Value not found for type appengine.Context

```
<pre>github.com/go-martini/martini/router.go:320 (0xc3731d)
    (*routeContext).run: panic(err)
github.com/go-martini/martini/router.go:221 (0xc36729)
    (*route).Handle: context.run()
github.com/go-martini/martini/router.go:112 (0xc35628)
    (*router).Handle: route.Handle(context, res)
app/nc_backend.go:37 (0xc30fe0)
    Router.Handle.fm: m.Action(r.Handle)
go/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:340 (0xc23b82)
go/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:474 (0xd41bd3)
go/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:345 (0xd40c65)
github.com/codegangsta/inject/inject.go:102 (0xd8449a)
    (*injector).Invoke: return reflect.ValueOf(f).Call(in), nil
github.com/go-martini/martini/martini.go:165 (0xc33607)
    (*context).run: _, err := c.Invoke(c.handler())
github.com/go-martini/martini/martini.go:156 (0xc33500)
    (*context).Next: c.run()
github.com/go-martini/martini/recovery.go:140 (0xc37a4b)
    func.004: c.Next()
go/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:339 (0xc23b22)
go/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:474 (0xd41bd3)
go/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:345 (0xd40c65)
github.com/codegangsta/inject/inject.go:102 (0xd8449a)
    (*injector).Invoke: return reflect.ValueOf(f).Call(in), nil
github.com/go-martini/martini/martini.go:165 (0xc33607)
    (*context).run: _, err := c.Invoke(c.handler())
github.com/go-martini/martini/martini.go:69 (0xc32b08)
    (*Martini).ServeHTTP: m.createContext(res, req).run()
go/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1496 (0xc98dda)
go/src/pkg/appengine_internal/api_prod.go:246 (0xc26e3f)
go/src/pkg/appengine_internal/api_prod.go:212 (0xc268c5)
go/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:340 (0xc23b82)
go/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:474 (0xd41bd3)
go/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:345 (0xd40c65)
_:410 (0xcf6255)
go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:279 (0xc170a0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`appengine.Context` is an interface, so you have to use the alternative `MapTo`. Also, according to the docs, mapping should be performed on the martini Context, not on the Martini object itself.

So your code should be:

```
m.Use(func(c martini.Context, req *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)
    ctx, err := appengine.Namespace(ctx, namespace)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Debugf("[Namespace] %s", err)
    }
    c.MapTo(ctx, (*appengine.Context)(nil))
})
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you very much! It needs a bit editing with ctx in appengine.Namespace but it works :)